# Merge two pandas dataframe two create a new dataframe with a specific operation

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have two dataframes as shown below.

```
Company Name    BOD Position    Ethnicity   DOB Age Gender  Degree ( Specialazation)    Remark
0   Big Lots Inc.   David J. Campisi    Director, President and Chief Executive Offic...    American    1956    61  Male    Graduate    NaN
1   Big Lots Inc.   Philip E. Mallott   Chairman of the Board   American    1958    59  Male    MBA, Finace NaN
2   Big Lots Inc.   James R. Chambers   Independent Director    American    1958    59  Male    MBA NaN
3   Momentive Performance Materials Inc Mahesh Balakrishnan director    Asian   1983    34  Male    BA Economics    NaN


    Company Name    Net Sale    Gross Profit    Remark
0   Big Lots Inc.   5.2B    2.1B    NaN
1   Momentive Performance Materials Inc 544M    146m    NaN
2   Markel Corporation  5.61B   2.06B   NaN
3   Noble Energy, Inc.  3.49B   2.41B   NaN
4   Leidos Holding, Inc.    7.04B   852M    NaN
```

I want to create a new dataframe with these two, so that in 2nd dataframe, I have new columns with count of ethinicities from each companies, such as American -2 Mexican -5 and so on, so that later on, i can calculate diversity score.

the variables in the output dataframe is like,

```
Company Name    Net Sale    Gross Profit    Remark  American    Mexican German .....
 Big Lots Inc.   5.2B    2.1B    NaN    2    0   5   ....
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First get counts per groups by [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with [`size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html) and [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.unstack.html), last [`join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) to second `DataFrame`:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Company Name':list('aabcac'),
                    'Ethnicity':['American'] * 3 + ['Mexican'] * 3})
df1 = df1.groupby(['Company Name', 'Ethnicity']).size().unstack(fill_value=0)
#slowier alternative 
#df1 = pd.crosstab(df1['Company Name'], df1['Ethnicity'])
print (df1)
Ethnicity     American  Mexican
Company Name                   
a                    2        1
b                    1        0
c                    0        2

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Company Name':list('abc')})
print (df2)
  Company Name
0            a
1            b
2            c

df3 = df2.join(df1, on=['Company Name'])
print (df3)
  Company Name  American  Mexican
0            a         2        1
1            b         1        0
2            c         0        2
```

EDIT: You need replace unit by `0` and convert to `float`s:

```
print (df)
  Name  sale
0    A  100M
1    B  200M
2    C    5M
3    D   40M
4    E   10B
5    F    2B


d = {'M': '0'*6, 'B': '0'*9}
df['a'] = df['sale'].replace(d, regex=True).astype(float).sort_values(ascending=False)
print (df)
  Name  sale             a
0    A  100M  1.000000e+08
1    B  200M  2.000000e+08
2    C    5M  5.000000e+06
3    D   40M  4.000000e+07
4    E   10B  1.000000e+10
5    F    2B  2.000000e+09
```

Comment: Thanks @jezrael, I have a question, if you see in second dataframe, I have a column sale and profile, like 5.2B and 146m, how can i convert it to continous numeral value, like for 5.2B = 5200000000 and 146000000.